How to avoid infinite recursion in CTE?
GROUP_MEMBER is a table that contains all Active Directory Group membership.
It is of the following structure:
CN_GroupName nvarchar(64)
CN_MemberName nvarchar(64),
Member_Is_Group nchar(1),  -- "Y" if CN_MemberName is the name of an AD Group
GroupDomain nvarchar(128),
GroupParent nvarchar(128),
GroupName nvarchar(128),
GroupClass nvarchar(128),
GroupGUID nvarchar(128),
UserDomain nvarchar(128),
UserParent nvarchar(128),
UserName nvarchar(128),
UserClass nvarchar(128),
UserGUID nvarchar(128),

Here's the query:
WITH GroupMembers AS (
    SELECT CN_GroupName, CN_MemberName, Member_Is_Group, ..., 1 as [level]
    FROM dbo.GROUP_MEMBER
), ExpandedGroupMembers AS ( -- gm1

    SELECT CN_GroupName, CN_MemberName, CN_GroupName AS DirectGroup,Member_Is_Group, ..., [level] +1 as Lev
    FROM GroupMembers

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT gm1.CN_GroupName, gm2.CN_MemberName, gm1.CN_MemberName AS DirectGroup, gm2.Member_Is_Group, ..., [level] as lev
    FROM ExpandedGroupMembers AS gm1
    INNER JOIN GroupMembers AS gm2 ON gm1.CN_MemberName = gm2.CN_GroupName
    WHERE gm1.Member_Is_Group = 'Y'
)

SELECT lev, *
FROM ExpandedGroupMembers as FinalResult
ORDER BY cn_groupname

It works fine until you run into a condition where GROUP A contains GROUP B, GROUP B contains GROUP C, and GROUP C contains GROUP A, creating a circular reference.
When it encounters this, an infinite loop occurs and the statement gets cancelled.
Here's the query.  How can I avoid the infinite recursion?
This question:  Recursive CTE result is infinite
...poses a similar scenario, but it involves joining a different table in the recursion query.  I need to join the same table (I think.  I don't know.  That's why I'm asking for help).

Keep track of previously visited groups by doing something like: '_' + GroupName + PrevGroupName and make sure currently joined group isn't contained inside the above group path

This can be done with cursors that navigate the graph that represents the table as long as you save the path previously traveled and exclude rows already traveled.
It is a common problem in the courses of data structures, in the lesson of graphs.

This question is similar to: SQL Recursion CTE infinite loop. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You don't need a cursor, a recusiveCTE will work

When building your visited nodes list, it is important to: (1) Choose a delimiter that cannot be part of the data. (2) Ensure that your list also starts and ends with that delimiter - for example ',A,' and ',A,B,C,'. (3) Ensure that your terminating condition also include starting and ending delimiters - for example VisitedList NOT LIKE CONCAT('%,', NextNode, ',%') which becomes something like VisitedList NOT LIKE '%,B,%'.

My original "duplicate" question linked above had a non-functional answer. This question and this question have what I believe to be better answers that show the proper use of visited list delimiters. Also, I'll add to my earlier "important to do" list (4) Cast the initial visited node value to a long string type like varchar(max) or nvarchar(max) to ensure that the recursive part of the CTE has sufficient space to expand that list.
